# Access initialValues in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-redux-form

I have a use case where I need to access a particular index of initialValues of React-Redux. InitialValues looks like object `{"appName": "test"}`
but When I try to use it like this:

```js
if (Object.keys(this.props.initialValues).length > 0){
  appName = this.props.initialValues["appName"]
}
```

I get the following error:

> TTS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Partial<{}>' has no index signature.

Is there a way I can use this value or get this to work?

Comment: Which line is the error pointing to?

Comment: Initial values of `react-redux`? Do you mean `redux-form`?

Comment: it's pointing here appName = this.props.initialValues["appName"]

Comment: react-redux-form initialValues